# python for k, g in iterpools.groupby(str): list(g) will change in the 'if' statement

Tags: python

As a newbie, I try to practice the function of groupby and see the result. However, I find a weird phenomenon。

```
    str = 'hieeelalaooo'
    for k, g in groupby(str):
        print(list(k), list(g))
        if True:
            print(list(k), list(g))
```

The result shows that list(g) will change in the 'if' statement like below:

```
`['h'] ['h']
 ['h'] []
 ['i'] ['i']
 ['i'] []
 ['e'] ['e', 'e', 'e']
 ['e'] []
 ....`
```

I just can't get it. In my intuition, list(g) should be unchanged rather than becoming a empty list. Could anyone please explain the underlying logic for such change? I am really appreciated for your help.

Comment: Following the documentation, the variable's content is discharged after it was generated.
So, if you want to keep the values you have to store them in another variable

Comment: g is an iterator, this means it has a state to remember which items it already returned (for the first list) and which not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because `g` is an `iterator`, i.e. `groupby` returned the value of `g` through a `yield` statement. Once you've used that value it is gone unless you assign it to another variable, this is because it doesn't keep the yielded values in memory.

You could do this:

```
str = 'hieeelalaooo'
    for k, g in groupby(str):
        k_ = k
        g_ = g
        print(list(k_), list(g_))
        if True:
            print(list(k_), list(g_))
```

For more information, check out: https://www.pythoncentral.io/python-generators-and-yield-keyword/

Comment: That really makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for taking the time to mark the answer as correct and for commenting with your feedback, it's actually very appreciated; not many new SO users take the time to do this. Wish you a nice day!